# Why do I have conda error in VS Code for running a python file?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda

I've been trying to get used to VS Code, and following their video tutorials.

I followed their debugging [video](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/introvideos/debugging) and applied similar thing myself, however I get the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2rrv.png) about conda.

I don't see any print outputs on the screen, nor I can't use the input function in the code.

Is there something that I'm missing or doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Seems like you didn't registered conda in your system's path environment variable. It means that you need register conda in your path (try this or another one guide from google https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/python_install-conda) or, if you don't want to edit path by yourself and if you don't have any usefull environments, you can reinstall anaconda with accepting "add conda to my path" checkbox on one of steps.

Comment: it is also important for you to distinguish whether you interact with VSCode itself either with powershell. You send ```conda``` command to powershell, so it's not VSCode's problem that this command is not registered in your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the reason, but found a solution: changing the interpreter from Anaconda to another one solved the problem for me. In order to change it:

1. Ctrl+Shift+P for command palette
2. Search for "Select Interpreter"
3. Select a working [interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjfrp.png)

Comment: this solution works beacuse VSCode calls registered in path command (python or python3) or interpreter directly

Comment: @gpinigin thank you for your help in the comments.